# Where to store Social Login Oauth2 access tokens

Tags: java, spring, rest, security, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to build a Spring Boot REST API that will implement social login(Spotify). After successful login with Spotify, I would like to store the Spotify access_token in my JWT token that I'm generating to be able to access my backend. I need a Spotify access token to be able to make API calls to Spotify(almost every request to my app will need to call Spotify API). Is it a good practice to store access tokens to external services in JWT? Or should I store the access token in my DB and read it when I need it? Maybe do you have any guides on how to implement stateless REST API that will call external services?

Answer (score 0):

usually, I store access token in Redis, it's faster then DB. if you use DB, every quest will link DB twice，one for get user infomation(like username and password)，one for read the access token. When the frequency of quest is very small，it's ok. but when the frequency of quest more and more, store in DB, will very waste of performance. Use Redis have another advantage，it has expire time. So, most of my project, I use Redis store token.

Comment: Hmm, and what are the other possibilities? Is there any guide on how should this be implemented in Spring-boot?

Comment: @GeorgeGuguli  or maybe you don't have to store access token，you can save the user information and expiration date in token，and then encipher.  Spring Oauth2 just need verify token is effective. And the guide，if you really want store token，you can see Official documentation [Interface TokenStore](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/TokenStore.html)

Comment: Hmm, I need that Spotify Access token to make API calls to Spotify. So I need to store it somewhere.